# Hide loop if no posts exist

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, hide

I simply have a single loop that's pulling through a CPT, but I would like to hide the whole container div of the loop, if it has no posts...

I'm trying various iterations of this if statement surrounding the container:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I can't seem to get it to work properly... The full code blog is here:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

<div class="container default-strip-section">
<h2><?php the_field('vacancies_title'); ?></h2>
<div class="row justify-content-center">

    <?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'vacancies',
          'posts_per_page' => 9999
          // 'orderby' => 'title',
          // 'order'   => 'ASC'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts()  ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-12">  
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <p><?php the_title() ?></p>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>

</div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure I'm missing something simple! Thanks for looking!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rank's answer is nearly correct -- it needs the object instance before `the_post()` again:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'vacancies',
    'posts_per_page' => 9999, // If you're wanting to show all posts, use -1 here.
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    ?>

    <div class="container default-strip-section">
    
        <h2><?php the_field('vacancies_title'); ?></h2>
        
        <div class="row justify-content-center">

            <?php
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            $the_query->the_post();
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-12">  
                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                </div>

                <?php
            endwhile;
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Ah thank you, Shoelaced! I understand what was missing now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the html of the container after the if `have_posts()`, where you check if there are any posts. This way the whole container is not displayed when the if is not true.
But you are using a ACF field of the post where you are showing this list of vacancies. So we save the id into a variable to be able to view the value inside of your custom query called `the_query` (this is not a self-explanatory / good name). Why not call it `vacancies_query` to have a more readable code. Putting it together it should look like this:

```
<?php
    $current_post = get_the_ID();
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'vacancies',
        'posts_per_page' => 9999
    );
    $vacancies_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $vacancies_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="container default-strip-section">
            <h2><?php the_field('vacancies_title', $current_post); ?></h2>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <?php while ( $vacancies_query->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12">  
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <p><?php the_title() ?></p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    <?php else :
        /* nothing to see here */
    endif;
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you rank for this and explains a few ways to re-write it :) However when I add the code it seems to break the page - seems like its just spitting out <div class="col-md-12">  
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <p><?php the_title() ?></p>
                        </a>
                    </div> over and over without stopping... Im not sure how fix that? :-/

Comment: I'm not sure where you put this code. I removed the outer if clause, please check code again. I think you are putting this code inside a single post page? So the ACF field (vacancies-title) is set in the post? Do the vacancies have a relation to the post, so you need this specific h2 ? Please tell me some so I can help you out :)

Comment: I assume I don't need to include the outer if clause? - I've just replaced the whole thing with your new code so its sitting as is, inside a normal page template... but it's looping forever and eventually crashed my browser (well the browser stops it as its using a lot of data)...

Comment: oh also im not putting this into a single post page, its on a normal template page...

Comment: The custom post type os vacancies and has no taxonomies. Im attaching custom filed to a careers page template... the title of the vacancy just uses the post title there are no ACFs inside the vacancy CPT... so <?php the_title() ?> should show the title of the vacancy

Comment: maybe its the $vacancies_query->have_posts() part that's the issue? Im not too sure sorry...